Shower screen is not vertical, but is it within tolerance?
We have had our bathroom renovated. The frameless glass shower screen was installed yesterday and is not vertical.
I made an improvised plumb bob with cotton thread and a ball bearing. The shower screen is 2 metres high 1cm thick and is off vertical by about 1.3cm (measured at the bottom).
I suspect that when I raise this with the builder he will argue that it is "within tolerance".
Any advice appreciated.

If my math is correct the amount is really about 65/1000 of a percent.   Your homemade plumb bob can make that figure even smaller.   I don't see it as an issue.

@RMDman, it is 0.65% (650/1000 of a percent). If it was only 0.065% I would not be concerned.

Out by 1/2” over 7 feet is a little much, but fixing it is apt to introduce more problems with sealant and screw holes. I’d try to let it go.

Does it create functional problems? If not I'd led it slide.

@vidarlo It is mainly the look/aesthetics. To my untrained eye, it looks like the glass is very slightly bowed, rather than merely been installed on a slant, so that might be cause an issue in the future.

If the glass is bowed, that’s not an install issue — that’s a glass issue. Having said that, it’s extremely unlikely to be a functional problem in the future.

I don't get it. You put a floor down and 1/16 over 10 feet is acceptable but on a vertical line 1/2" over 7 feet is ok and live with it? You paid for it to look like something attractive, not as a way of explaining why it looks odd.
